# Is there a way to get the service name of a socket object in java

Tags: java, sockets, networking, service, protocols

For exmple I create this lines of code to connect the socket with IP and timeout arguments

```
           Socket mySocket = new Socket();
             mySocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.0.1", port),timeout); 


        if(mySocket.isConnected())
        {
        resp="Port: "+ Integer.toString(dir)+" is coneccted"+"<br>";
        }
        out.print(resp+mySocket.getPort());
```

but what I can´t do is to get the service name of the socket, I mean is there a method 
like socket.getService() or socket.getProtocol()

Comment: The socket connects through TCP protocol.

Comment: If you're connecting to a port you would normally already know what service you're expecting to connect to. Why don't you? NB The isConnected() test is redundant. If the socket wasn't connected an exception would have been thrown and the isConnected() test wouldn't be reachable.

Comment: So, for every port there is  an asociated service, I mean you can´t change it.

Comment: If that's a statement, it is incorrect. If it's a question, the answer is 'no'. The relevance escapes me in either case.